# Javascript player not working on Opera/Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So the problem is that I have a video and 2 buttons -

```
<div id="buttonOn"><img src="assets/playbl.png" onClick="videoStart()" ></div>
<div id="buttonOff"><img src="assets/pausebl.ico" onClick="videoStop()"></div>
```

My script is the following:

```
<script>
var vid = document.getElementById("videos");
videos.muted = false;
var buttonOn = document.getElementById("buttonOn");
var buttonOff = document.getElementById("buttonOff");
vid.onended = videoStop();
function videoStart()
{
    vid.play();
    buttonOn.style.display = 'none';
    buttonOff.style.display = 'block';

}

function videoStop()
{
    vid.pause();
    buttonOff.style.display = 'none';
    buttonOn.style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
```

When I click on buttonOn the video indeed starts but for as little as 2-3 seconds and then stops. On Edge the video works fine. After the video has "started" once when I click the buttonOff i get this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKYu8.jpg).

Comment: Constrain question posts to *single* questions - don't post two unrelated ones together.

Comment: Sorry. I fixed it.

Comment: And by fixed it i meant that I removed the second question.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues i see with the code, firstly the line `videos.muted = false;` should be `vid.muted = false`, thats the correct name of the variable. Secondly, there is an issue with your `onended` event handler. Remember you have to pass a reference to a function to an event handler, not the return value of a function execution. So you have to change `vid.onended = videoStop();` to `vid.onended = videoStop;`. Now when the video ends it correctly calls the videoStop function. I've added a snippet below using your code with the updates I mentioned, its working fine in chrome. Take a look to see if you still have issues.

```js
var vid = document.getElementById("videos");
vid.muted = false;
vid.onended = videoStop;
var buttonOn = document.getElementById("buttonOn");
var buttonOff = document.getElementById("buttonOff");
buttonOn.style.display = 'block';
buttonOff.style.display = 'none';
function videoStart()
{
    vid.play();
    buttonOn.style.display = 'none';
    buttonOff.style.display = 'block';

}

function videoStop()
{
    vid.pause();
    buttonOff.style.display = 'none';
    buttonOn.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.control{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<div id="buttonOn" onClick="videoStart()"><i class="material-icons control">play_arrow</i></div>
<div id="buttonOff" onClick="videoStop()"><i class="material-icons control">pause</i></div>


<video id="videos" src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"></video>
```

Comment: This is how I declare the video. I think that this can be the problem because even with your code I can't seem to turn on the video in Chrome. I'm using grids if it has any known issues and can help to resolve the problem.
`<video id="videos" style="height: 100%; width: auto; margin: 0 auto; box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); position: relative;">
     <source src="assets/mm.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     </video>` I saw a thread that said something that the video tag uses some kind of windows player which is an issue in browsers that don't support it...